# Get Checked Items In A DevExpress CheckedComboBoxEdit

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress 9.3 CheckedComboBoxEdit, and I need to get the collection of all checked items. It seems like this should be a simple task, but the closest thing I have found to a solution is something that says I can use:

```
CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.GetItems.GetCheckedValues()
```

Unfortunately, there is no GetCheckedValues method here. I have found the following:

```
CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.GetCheckedItems()
```

which returns an object, but I cannot find any reference on what I should cast the object as. I have also tried to iterate through the items, and check each one to see if it is checked, following the suggestion from [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q493701), but Items returns a collection of Strings, not CheckedListBoxItem, so I cannot test if they are checked.

What I want is a String collection of checked items; right now, I am okay to receive them as any type of collection, or even create the collection myself. I know there must be some very simple thing that I am overlooking, but I can't seem to find it.

**SOLUTION**

This is the solution that I came up with. I would prefer something more elegant; it seems like there should be a way to get the checked items, since this is what the control is for. Nevertheless, this seems to work:

```
Private Function GetChecked() As List(Of String)
    Dim checked As New List(Of String)
    Dim checkedString As String = CType(SitePickerControl.Properties.GetCheckedItems(), String)
    If (checkedString.Length > 0) Then
        checked.AddRange(checkedString.Split(New Char() {","c}))
    End If
    Return checked
End Function
```

If anyone can give me a proper solution, I would love to see it.

Comment: Do you mean the [windows forms DevExpress control CheckedComboBoxEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic)?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: That's the one I am using. I've come across that page several times while looking for a solution, but didn't see anything relating to getting the checked values.

Comment: In newer versions there is a SelectedItems collection that gives you back all the checked items. I assume 9.3 does not have that? Perhaps it is specific to the developement environment. Is this Winforms, WPF, Silverlight...

Comment: @Steve: I searched for SelectedItems under SitePickerControl, .Properties, and .Items, but it didn't show up in this version. This is a Winforms application. I just don't see how they could release without adding an accessor for the selected items.

Comment: Sorry, I checked and the CheckedComboEdit does NOT have that, it was the CheckedListBox I was thinking of. Don't see why they would be any different???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I use:

```cs
var ids = (from CheckedListBoxItem item in checkedComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items
           where item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked
           select (int)item.Value).ToArray();
```

You can also make an extension method on `CheckedListBoxItem` which will return only checked items values.

(It's C#, not VB, but the concept is the same.)

Comment: This looks similar to what I eventually wound up doing, and since it is the first "answer", I'll accept it. I hope this provides help for someone in the future. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I should pitch in anyway.

I'm not sure on when v9.3 was released, but there definitely is a GetCheckedValues() function now. It is described here:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsCheckedListBoxItemCollection_GetCheckedValuestopic

and I also found it as the answer in one of their support cases (which is much older than this post) here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q431364

So to get a list of all the selected values you need something like:

```
myCombo.Properties.GetItems().GetCheckedValues()
```

or to check if a specific value was selected:

```
if (myCombo.Properties.GetItems().GetCheckedValues().contains("myvalue"))
```

I hope this helps future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

For VB.NET

```
Dim ids = (From item In checkedComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items Where item.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Select CInt(item.Value)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
var ids = (checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Where(m => m.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)).Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```