# Get Checked active value in a CheckedComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to know how to get checked active in a CheckedComboBoxEdit for save the values actives in a DataBase.
I have a list with N amount of data and I want to save only active data.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can get a collection of checked items using the
>   [CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.GetItems.GetCheckedValues()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsCheckedListBoxItemCollection_GetCheckedValuestopic)
>   method. It just return the value of the checked items in the
>   underlying list control.

To accomplish this task, you can also use the following approach:

```
    string items = string.Empty;
    foreach (CheckedListBoxItem item in checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.GetItems())
        if (item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            items += string.Format("{0} YES \r\n", item.Description);
        else
            items += string.Format("{0} NO \r\n", item.Description);
    items = items.TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray());
    XtraMessageBox.Show(items);
```

**More references:**

[Get Checked Items In A DevExpress CheckedComboBoxEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103003/get-checked-items-in-a-devexpress-checkedcomboboxedit)
[How to iterate through through CheckedComboBoxEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q364726)
[How to retrieve the checked items in the CheckedComboBoxEdit control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q493701)

Comment: Thanks Niranjan! I'm trying with the CheckedCombo, but this show me a invalid value Error. Apparently, I can't put two checked selection.

Comment: show some code where you are getting error. .them may be it will be easy to understand the exact issue.

Comment: This is my code  
`private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            EntidadRentas reg = new EntidadRentas();  
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Count; i++)  
            {
                    CheckedListBoxItem item = checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items[i];  
                    if (item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)  
                    {  
                        Renta.PeliculaId = (int)item.Value;  
                        ShowWaitDialog();  
                        try  
                        {...`

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time that I use this.  Well, the point is, when I want to select two checks, the control put a 'X' in a red circle, and the message says "Invalid Value". I want to save each record by my List.

Comment: Go through the referenced link.. there are few sample projects are attached. try to run them and observe the behaviour of this control. Hope these let you solve the issue.

Comment: I review it. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try this one

```
CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.GetItems.GetCheckedValues()
```

And please let me know if it works for you.

More info about CheckedComboBoxEdit members :
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEditMembersTopicAll

Comment: It's working! Thanks! :)